# Cisco 1250 Series AP, DHCP is not assigning IP Addresses remains at 0.0.0.0

Tags: cisco, access-point

As the title states, AP does not proceed beyond anonymous.
Just a rookie here. Is there an "enable" that I missed. Using the Browser GUI to set-up.
Should I read the 500 page Configuration Guide?
Feel free to chuckle and all suggestions gratefully accepted.
Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Is this an Autonomous AP or Lightweight? If Lightweight - you'll need to ensure that whatever network you are using for management purposes has the correct DHCP options (typically option 43 tells the AP where the Controller is, and Option 60 will indicate brand of AP). Do you have CLI Access to the switch where the AP is plugged into? If so - can you see MAC addresses being learned on that switch port? If you do see MAC addresses being learned on the port, do they have valid ARP table entries on the 'routing point' for that network? I would also echo the other response here - consoling into th

Comment: We're running CISCO AIR-AP1252G-A-K9 IOS ACCESS POINTS in Autonomous mode. These are connected to a single Ubee DD365 Cable Modem. I'll work on getting links to the screen shots, the boot script and the assocaiation page of the GUI which shows two units connected and two at 0.0.0.0

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect a computer on the same switch port does it obtain an IP address trough DHCP?

To understand what's going on, you will have to connect a serial console, then look at the console messages when the AP boot.

You will find a less-than-500-pages guide here :

[Quick Start Guide: Cisco Aironet 1250 Series Access Point](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1250/quick/guide/ap1250qs.html#wp41325)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I will try laptop to cable modem port (which I did not state previously) tomorrow. I can connect via the CLI and have copied image file that way. Here is a scrn sht of the tail of the boot.

Comment: Guess not. The boot script is 6400 characters too long.